# ggplot geom_col: making certain axis count integers rather than summing

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently making a hate crime case study. For my plot I am using one zip-code as my y-axis and plotting how many crimes and what group is being targeted on the x-axis using geom-col. The problem is my y-axis is adding the zip-codes together rather than counting each frequency of how many times the zip-code shows up. Here is my dataset looks like:

```
structure(list(ID = 1:5, CRIME_TYPE = c("VANDALISM", "ASSAULT", "VANDALISM", "ASSAULT", 
"OTHER"), BIAS_MOTIVATION_GROUP = c("ANTI-BLACK                                   ", 
"ANTI-BLACK                                   ", "ANTI-FEMALE HOMOSEXUAL (LESBIAN)             ", 
"ANTI-MENTAL DISABILITY                       ", "ANTI-JEWISH                                  "),
 ZIP_CODE = c(40291L, 40219L, 40243L, 40212L, 40222L
)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is  my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- read.csv(file = "LMPD_OP_BIAS.csv", header = T)    
library(tidyverse)
hate_crime <- df %>%
  filter(ZIP_CODE == "40245")

hate_crime_plot <- hate_crime %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = BIAS_MOTIVATION_GROUP, y = ZIP_CODE, fill = 
                  BIAS_MOTIVATION_GROUP)) +
  geom_col() + labs(x = "BIAS_MOTIVATION_GROUP", fill = "BIAS_MOTIVATION_GROUP") +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text (angle =45, hjust =1))
print(hate_crime_plot)

hate_crime_ploter <- hate_crime %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = UOR_DESC, y = ZIP_CODE, fill = 
                  UOR_DESC)) +
  geom_col() + labs(x = "UOR_DESC", fill = "UOR_DESC") +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text (angle =45, hjust =1))
print(hate_crime_ploter)
```

For full data visit here: [visit site to download data set](https://data.louisvilleky.gov/dataset/lmpd-hate-crimes)

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing the plots from your code and data; could you try to make this a self-contained reproducible example?

Comment: I just made the data set downloadable.

Comment: As you want the counts... maybe you want `ggplot(., aes(x = BIAS_MOTIVATION_GROUP, fill = BIAS_MOTIVATION_GROUP)) + geom_bar()`?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I think you've got a couple issues here. What's happening in your code is you're asking ggplot to make a bar plot with a categorical variable (`BIAS_MOTIVATION_GROUP` and `UOR_DESC`) on the x-axis and a continuous variable (`ZIP_CODE`) on the y-axis. Since there are more than one row per x-y combination, ggplot adds things together by x value, which is what you'd expect out of a bar plot. Long story short, I wonder if what you actually want is a **histogram** here. Your dataset (`hate_crime`) only has one value of `ZIP_CODE`, so I'm not sure what plotting ZIP on the y-axis is supposed to visualize. A histogram would look like this:

```
hate_crime %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = UOR_DESC, , fill = UOR_DESC)) +
  geom_histogram(stat = "count") + 
  labs(x = "UOR_DESC", fill = "UOR_DESC") +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text (angle =45, hjust =1))
```

[image]

If, instead, you're trying to visualize how often each ZIP code shows up in each category, you'd have to approach things differently. Perhaps you're looking for something like this?

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = UOR_DESC, fill = factor(ZIP_CODE))) +
  geom_histogram(stat = "count") + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text (angle =45, hjust =1))
```

[image]